# C# ConnectionString on app.config not working on other computers

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm building a school project application that has a connection to a SQL Server database.

On my computer, the program works flawlessly, however, when I built it and send it to another computer for testing, I'm getting an unhandled exception that I can only assume is the connection not being successful.

I'm using an app.config, with the connection string as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TEAMSConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\MYSQL;Initial Catalog=TEAMS;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Can someone help me write a connection string that should work on all computers?

Comment: can show the handle exception?

Comment: Please post the stack trace details. Connection string tells me that application is connecting to MYSQL running on local computer as it does not have server name in it. So,does the other computer has MYSQL installed on their box?

Comment: string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TEAMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString; 

This is where the exception happens: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\MYSQL
```

It looks like your database is located on your local machine.  That's what the `.` means in the connection string. It's short for `localhost`.  So it doesn't work on the other computer because it is looking for the database on its own localhost, or on itself.

To get this to work on other machines, you will either need to migrate your database to a server that is more widely available (good idea) or somehow give the other computers network access to your computer (not a good idea).

But either way, the connection string will need to point to something else other than "localhost" or every computer that runs the app will try and find the database on itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the answer. You can probably get a free small hosted database for free (with limitations) from azure. That would make it easy for you to have a hosted sql server you can connect to from any machine

Comment: As it turns out, our teacher also has the exact same database on his machine and therefore "Data Source =(local)" ended up working just fine.

Comment: @Johnny, cool! That will work so long as every machine that tries to run the app also has the database on itself. But it will cause problems long term. But, for just learning and in a class room setting, it's all good!